# Do BLE HCI_EVT occupy a packet slot on the connection interval?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have been analizing the Bluetooth snoop file on several Android devices, where the Android device is the Central (Client) and the peer device is the Peripheral (Server).

When performing a Write Command (WC) (sending data from Android to Peripheral), besides the WC sent packet, wireshark identifies an HCI event labeled as `Number of Completed Packets`.

As HCI messages are exchanged between Host and Controller of the same device, do these events take up a packet slot on the Connection Interval(CI) ? Because while I'm able to send 3 packets/CI using Notifications, only 1 packets/CI is being sent when using Write Command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send multiple Write Without Response packets (called Write Command on the ATT layer) in a single connection event. The bluetooth controller has a buffer where it enqueues outgoing packets (called ACL data packets). You can see the size of this queue in the snoop log by looking for LE Read Buffer Size. When bluetooth is started, the host reads this value will keep track of the currently available space in some counter variable. When it sends a packet to the device (for example a Write Command), the counter is decreased by one. When the host receives a Number of Completed Packets event (which means that the packet has been sent out over the air), it increases the counter. As long as this counter remains positive after you issue a Write Without Response, your GATT onCharacteristicWrite callback will be called so you can immediately enqueue another Write Without Response packet. When the next connection event occurs, it sends multiple packets that are enqueued.

If you still can't achieve throughput higher than one packet per connection event, make sure you have set up the characteristic to use the WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE.